# NullInjectorError: No provider for Router! in Package

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I built a module A and put it into a package via

```
call npm run build-release
call npm pack dist/
```

Then I installed it to another Angular module B with

```
npm install
```

Module A has a component that I use in module B, this component (in A) injects a router in its constructor and subscribes to router events:

```
constructor(private router: Router)
```

I keep getting an error from this component:

```
BComponent.html:8 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AComponent -> Router]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AComponent -> Router]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
```

Do I have to provide the Router of BComponent to AComponent somehow?

Everything works fine for each module itself and also if I just copy AModule into BModule. The error only occurs if I pack AModule and install it via npm in BModule.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I've added Router as a provider in my unit tests, but not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have made mistake in `AppModule` file import route in `AppModule`.

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = []; // Define your route

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```